# (Re)starting Matlab after error from error location

Tags: debugging, matlab

I'm debugging a matlab script that takes ~10 minutes to run. Towards the end of the script I do some i/o and simple calculations with my results, and I keep running into errors. Is there a way to start matlab from a certain sport in a script after it exits with an error--the data is still in the workspace so I could just comment out all of the code up until the error point, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a better way to go about doing this without rerunning the entire script (the ultra-lazy/inefficient way)?

Thanks,

Colorado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use [`dbstop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dbstop.html). Type `dbstop if error` and then run your script. The minute it hits an error, it will create a breakpoint there and you're in the workspace of the script --- which means you can debug the error, save data ; anything you want! Here's a snippet from the documentation for `dbstop if error` --- there are other ways to do `dbstop`, so do check it out:

> `dbstop if error`
>
> Stops execution when any MATLAB program file you subsequently run produces a run-time error, putting MATLAB in debug mode, paused at the line that generated the error. The errors that stop execution do not include run-time errors that are detected within a `try...catch` block. You cannot resume execution after an uncaught run-time error. Use dbquit to exit from debug mode.

Comment: However, once you arrive at the error, you can select the remaining code and choose `Evaluate Selection` from the context menu. Thus, you can run a fixed version of the line that threw the error, as well as running the rest of the code (which e.g. saves all the results to file)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is saving me a lot of time

Comment: @user471949: No problem! It was an eye-opener for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

Double percent signs will enable 'cell mode' which lets you run little blocks of code in steps.  Sounds like just what youre looking for.

Comment: Very helpful tip for general "unit" tests, thanks for the answer